# Use binary file or JSON file if one want to make arrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, json, webgl, arraybuffer

I want to obtain some data for my webgl app. I need to use these data with shaders, so I have to put them into ArrayBuffer. Now what I have here are two very similar code fragments. 
First one should work with binary files:

```
function readBinaryFile(file) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', file, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = function (e) {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                var buffer = request.response;
                // here I already have a Buffer, 
                // so Im just constructing TypedArray 
                var result = new Float32Array(buffer, 64, 4*3*250 );
            } else {
                console.error(request.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
};

readBinaryFile('data/file.bin'));
```

And the second should work with json files:

```
function readJSONFile(file) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', file, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = function (e) {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                // here I dont have a buffer, so 
                // it will create both Buffer and TypedArray
                var result = new Float32Array(jsonData.vertexPositions);
            } else {
                console.error(request.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
};

readJSONFile('data/file.json'));
```

I like json files for its structure and I saw that a lot of people use it. But I feel like it is a little bit dirty since I do things that I dont have to do like parse large json or requesting responseText instead of binary data. I would rather use json way, but my application should be really great and fast, so maybe it doesnt worth...

So my question is if **anybody thinks about it too and did for example some tests with it.** Thank you.

PS: Thinking about 100MB data that are already in browser data storage or maybe some data loading on the run...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you are running your own server, you can gzip compress your data and tell the server to tell the browser the data is gzipped and it will un-gzip it behind the scenes after it's downloaded. [Here's at least one question about that](https://serverfault.com/questions/78469/apache-send-pre-packed-gziped-files).

In that case you might find sending the text is smaller than sending the binary since text is easier to compress.

Another thing to consider is formatting your data and/or using a lossy format to get your data really small. As a simple example, if you're storing normals you might only send 8 bits for each X, Y, Z and then turn them back into floats when you load them or tell GL to do it for you. Another example is to quantize your positions. Meshes are usually stored using 32bit floats. You can compute the extents of your mesh and then store the data say in 16bits by converting each value as in

```
  smallX = Math.floor((x - minX) * 65535 / (maxX - minX));
```

After loading you can get back to something close to the original values with

```
  originalX = smallX * (maxX - minX) / 65535 + minX;
```

[There's a library that puts these concepts into practice to make very small meshes here](https://code.google.com/p/webgl-loader/).

The only issue you need to be aware of is sending binary data is not cross platform. If your original platform is little endian and the user's browser is big endian it won't work. Libraries like the one above probably handle that issue. On the other hand there are no common big endian platforms with WebGL capable browsers at the moment so maybe you can ignore this issue. Who knows what the future holds though.